# Group values in select2

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

**Usecase**: I am trying to group values in select2. For example: first 4 values should come in one group and the others should come in the second group. By grouping I mean the `<optgroup>` tag.

**Code**:

```js
let el = document.getElementById('role');

createSelect2("role", 'role', el);

function createSelect2(elementId, elementName, parent) {
  var select = document.createElement('select');
  select.setAttribute('id', elementId);
  select.setAttribute('name', elementName);
  parent.append(select);
  var parameters = {}
  var values = buildGroup();
  parameters.width = '90%';
  parameters.data = values;
  $(select).select2(parameters);
  return select;
}

function buildGroup() {
    let roles = ['role 1', 'role 2', 'role 3', 'role 4', 'role 5', 'role 6', 'role 7', 'role 8', 'role 9', 'role 10', 'role 11', 'role 12', 'role 13', 'role 14', 'role 15',]
    let valuesGroup1 = [roles[0], roles[1], roles[2], roles[3]];
    let valuesGroup2 = [];
    for (index = 4; index < roles.length; index++) {
        valuesGroup2.push(roles[index]);
    }
    let group1Obj = ['{"text" : "Common Groups", "children" : "' + valuesGroup1 + '"}', '{"text" : "Other Groups", "children" : "' + valuesGroup2 + '"}'];
    return group1Obj;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<div id="role">
</div>
```

**Problem**: It doesn't render the data in groups. Instead, it concatenate the data and show only two values.

I was referring this: https://select2.org/data-sources/formats#grouped-data

Here is the jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s8yoz2aL/1/

Comment: Your `group1Obj` currently contains two strings only. Not JSON. And the way you added `valuesGroup1` is incorrect. Don't concatenate an array with a string.

Comment: I even hardcoded a valid json and even that is not working.

 `let group1Obj = '[{"text": "Group 1", "children" : [{"id": 1, "text": "Option 1.1"},{"id": 2,"text": "Option 1.2"}]},{"text": "Group 2", "children" : [{"id": 3,"text": "Option 2.1"},{"id": 4,"text": "Option 2.2"}]}]';`

Comment: Still, you mixed up a string and JSON. Look at the answer, just revised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comment, the `group1Obj` is set incorrectly. Here is the fix:

```
function buildGroup() {
    let roles = ['role 1', 'role 2', 'role 3', 'role 4', 'role 5', 'role 6', 'role 7', 'role 8', 'role 9', 'role 10', 'role 11', 'role 12', 'role 13', 'role 14', 'role 15',]
    let valuesGroup1 = [{"id": 0, "text": roles[0]}, {"id": 1, "text": roles[1]}, {"id": 2, "text": roles[2]}, {"id": 3, "text": roles[3]}];
    let valuesGroup2 = [];
    for (index = 4; index < roles.length; index++) {
        valuesGroup2.push(roles[index]);
    }
  
  var jsonGroup1 = {"text" : "Common Groups"};
  jsonGroup1.children = valuesGroup1;
  var jsonGroup2 = {"text" : "Other Groups"};
  jsonGroup2.children = valuesGroup2;
  
  console.log(jsonGroup1);
  
    let group1Obj = [jsonGroup1, jsonGroup2];
    return group1Obj;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f5krznuc/2/)

Comment: In your fiddle, the search does not work